# property doesn't set after lazy initialization objective-c

Tags: objective-c, properties, boolean, lazy-initialization

I have a BOOL property and at the start this property equals NO. I want to set this property to YES from the start of my program, but with opportunity to toggle it.
For this, I made this getter:

```
-(BOOL)turn
{
    if(!_turn)
        _turn = YES;
    return _turn;
}
```

This getter set my turn property to YES, but it makes it "constant", always YES. 
Why?

I thought

```
if(!_turn)
```

construction is specially for the reason where you want set the "not set yet" object value

Can you answer me why this is so? And how can I set my property value to what i want. Thanks.

Comment: Question is not clear...

Comment: @BhanuPrakash after this getter, I can't set my turn property to NO. For example: `self.turn = !self.turn;` the result will be YES because of getter, I think but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your action table:

```
turn:     False          True
!turn   turn = YES      Do Nothing
```

When `_turn` is false, you flip it too true. When `_turn` is true, you do nothing (there's no else statement). Then you return the value of `_turn`. So yea, you are returning true in all cases.

To be honest, the design is not very good. If you want to set the initial value of the variable to a certain value, do that in the `init` method. Then provide another method that simply toggles the value:

```
-(BOOL) toggleTurn {
  _turn = !_turn;
  return _turn;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually the lazy initialization technique is used with pointers to objects, not with primitive types. This because a *BOOL* has only two possibile states: *NO* and *YES*, there isn't the "undefined state" which is usually associated with *nil* for objects.

The reason why it doesn't toggle is that you aren't toggling it, you are just setting it to *YES* when it's equal to *NO*, but you aren't handling the case when it's equal to *YES*. If you want to toggle it just do that:

```
-(BOOL)turn
{
    return _turn= !_turn;
}
```

**PS**: Whoever could argue that your method isn't properly a getter, because you are altering the variable before returning it. So I suggest to just return _turn without toggling it, and to create another separated method to toggle the variable.

Also I would like to mention that what you are doing is not called lazy initialization, I'll show you a case of lazy initialization:

```
// In the interface:
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSNumber* turnObject;
// In newer compiler versions it should be auto synthesized to _turnObject

// In the implementation: 
-(BOOL) turn
{
    // In this case I am not toggling it
    if(!_turnObject)        // Equal to if(turnObject==nil)
        _turnObject= @(NO); // Equal to _turnObject=[NSNumber numberWithBOOL: NO];
    return _turnObject;
}
```